# Number of unique ways in which the vertices in an undirected graph can be uniquely numbered from 1 to $V$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph with $V$ vertices, what is the number of unique ways in which each vertex can be uniquely numbered with the numbers 1 to $V$?

Note that this is not necessarily the number of ways in which the vertices can be ordered, i.e., $V!$, since some orderings may result in the same labeled graph (graph with labeled vertices). For example, in the extremely simple case of a graph with only two vertices and one edge, where the edge connects the two vertices, there is only one unique way to number the vertices, not $V!=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $$|V|! \over |\!\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$$where $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of $G$. To see this, imagine taking all $|V|!$ ways to label the vertices of the graph from $1$ to $|V|$, and grouping these labelings together whenever they differ by an automorphism. Each group will have size $|\!\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$, so the number of groups must be $|V|! \big/ |\!\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$.

Comment: If OP would like to determine the size of the graph's automorphism group, one would do well to cleverly apply the orbit-stabiliser theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used it to calculate the [symmetry factors of Feynman diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308385/formula-for-calculating-symmetry-factor-of-a-feynman-diagram). However, I'm not completely sure I arrived at the correct formula. Is that anything you have any experience with?